How do I get line-numbers to work in prismjs?
I have a stackblitz here with the most simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qvslgv?file=src%2Fmain.ts
I had attempted this in a much larger application and I assumed maybe my css was somehow overwriting it, so I made the simplest example and it still doesn't work. It seems a lot of people are having this problem. How does one get prism line numbers to work?
